# Understand equations containing unexplained terms and/or undefined variables?

Tags: publications

In scientific papers (main talking about STEM), surprisingly, there are many instances where authors introduce some mathematical equations and/or dynamical systems to explain a certain physical phenomena/system. However, they don't always define the variables they introduce. Just to a give the simplest example, they write y(x) = ax^2 + bx^3 + c, and it is clear that there is a reason why the equation contains the term  **bx^3**, but the authors don't explain why there is such a term, what the physical meaning of b is(i.e what it is quantifying), or what the term **bx^3** is accounting for.

If the paper is relatively new, it is usually possible to just email the authors and hope that they will answer in a reasonable amount of time (if they ever intend to do). However, if the paper is older, it is quite likely that even the authors won't remember such details.

In the latter case, i.e in the case of an old paper, what should one do to understand such an equation containing unexplained terms and/or undefined variables?

Comment: First, a good paper will always define all symbols.  Second, it is possible that the info being conveyed is not the exact meaning of each term, but the general structure or relationship between the terms.  Third, it is possible that the equation is so well established that the symbols no longer require explanation -- no one define the integral  symbol for example.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus, unfortunately, there are a lot of bad papers out there that one still needs to read it, regardless of how badly written they are

Comment: Do the calculation yourself?

Comment: @astronat if the problem exists during the section where they propose a model, you can't go "back" and do the calculations because there is no "back".

Comment: It's not really possible to answer this question without a specific example of what you think is an offending paper.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question that can have non-trivial answers ('work it out for yourself', 'find it explained somewhere else', 'give up'). One tip might be to carry on and read the rest of the paper - sometimes people miss things when re-drafting, and the explanation of 'why' gets separated from the place where it is introduced.

Comment: You will need to distinguish the cases that the paper is just "bad" and that the paper uses commonly agreed on concepts without explicitly naming or explaining them (this would make the "Preliminaries" section of some papers longer than the rest of the paper). The usual approach is to ask your advisor if you are a PhD student, ask the author whenever that is reasonable, or ask a peer or collaborator  with more experience in the concrete topic otherwise. If the paper is bad enough so that even without reasonable effort it cannot be used, then consider leaving it out.

Comment: Have you considered that the equation might be purely empirical and there is no clear scientific definition of its parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the discipline has a document(s) with background, generally-accepted definitions of symbols (it's amazing how many symbols are defined in the ISO 80000 series of standards, for example).

If that fails, maybe fire up the relevant discipline-specific SE site, and post a question like "Why do Bloggs et al. (1862, *Journal of Interesting Stuff* **8**:1-5) include the $bx^3$ term in their equation $y\left(x\right) = ax^2+bx^3+c$?"